# Customizar e-mail enviado pelo plugin wp e-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu utilizo o wp e-commerce em um site para os clientes fazerem cotações, mas gostaria de customizar o email que é enviado aos administradores do site quando um pedido é realizado.

Preciso fazer isso sem plugins de preferencia, pois são apenas algumas poucas alterações nos textos. Creio que tenha algum arquivo responsável por isso, onde posso encontrá-lo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, consegui encontrar o arquivo:

*wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/purchase-log-notification.class.php*

Nele podemos fazer alterações nas informações que são enviadas por e-mail.